# D3 4.0 dragging panning and zooming on canvas

Tags: d3.js

I am getting into D3 v4.0 and I struggle to add several behaviours on a canvas.

Usual setup:

```
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    var canvasContext = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

...with var simulation = d3.forceSimulation() ...

then:

```
    d3.select(canvas)
            .call(d3.drag()
            .container(canvas)
            .subject(dragsubject)
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended)
        );
    d3.select(canvas)
        .call(d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 4])
            .on("zoom", zoomed));
```

interestingly enough, when I start the page, my nodes move until they get balanced (as expected) and at that point, I can't zoom or pan.
Once the graph is stable, I can't drag nodes but I can zoom. So it is as if adding the .call(d3.zoom() created a layer on top of my graph that prevent mouse event to reach it (or maybe I can only add one .call to a given canvas)

Any thoughts on how to combine behaviours in v4.0?

Comment: and what is zoomed? Consider providing a minimal code representing your problem.

Comment: I wanted to zoom the whole canvas to see my graph better (hence putting the .call(canvas)
I basically took 2 of the new examples for D3 v4.0 and wanted them to work together
Creating a graph: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/ad70335eeef6d167bc36fd3c04378048)
and Zooming: [link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/d1f7b58631e71fbf9c568345ee04a60e)